# Different query params based on user input in search bar

Tags: ajax, reactjs, postgresql

I have a search bar where a user should be able to enter in either state, city, or zip code and get a list of results back. All of my data is from my own data set separated into columns location_state, location_city, and location_zip_code. 
I am able to get the user to search for only one value if I hardcode that query into the fetch request like so:

```
`http://localhost:8000/api/results?location_city=${this.state.searchTerm}`
```

However, I'm not sure how to make it so that the query changes based on what the user types in. So if the user types in a zip code, the query needs to be `location_zip_code=` or if they type in a state, it needs to be `location_state=`

I tried making an object with params equal to the search term, but as you can imagine, it added all of those params to the URL, which I don't want. This is what I have so far, which isn't working:

```
  fetchApi(method = 'GET', apiBody ) {
    const params = {
      location_city: this.state.searchTerm,
      location_state: this.state.searchTerm,
      location_zip_code: this.state.searchTerm,
    };
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(params));

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/results?' + urlParams + `=${this.state.searchTerm}`, {
      method: method,
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
// rest of code that isn't relevant.
```

I'm completely stuck on how to do this. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: How do you know if the user is typing a city, state or zip code? are they different fields on a form?

Comment: @SergioMoura Well that's kind of where I'm stuck. The user should have the option to search by either city, state, or zip code, but I'm not sure how it's supposed to distinguish between the three. If I figure that out, I'm sure I can get the fetch request to work.

Comment: How does your UI look, then?

Comment: @SergioMoura It's one search bar with a submit button that triggers a fetch request. A list of results should appear right under the search bar

Comment: only one search bar? like google? ok. Then you need to work on your postgresql query. Just make the query like google. `http://hostname:post/whatever?q=${userTextVariable}`. On your database query use: `SELECT yadayada FROM tableName WHERE location_city LIKE '%:q%' OR location_state LIKE '%:q%' OR location_zip_code LIKE '%:q%'`. I don't know what language you're using for backend, but essentially just replace the ":q" on the query string with what the user passed on the url parameter.

Comment: @Farah10 as Sergio sugest you need to use OR with like statements